# Masking textbox to accept only alphabets asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, masking

How do i mask a textbox to accept only alphabets.
using ajaxtool kit or regex or javascript (not jquery though).
Could i probably filter out numerics and special characters using ajaxtoolkit? 
Suggestions or answers please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "How do i mask a textbox to accept only alphabets." this sentence should be "How do i filter values for a textbox to accept only alphabets." Mask and Filter is two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Ajax Control Toolkit, here is sample code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbe" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="TextBox3"         
    FilterType="LowercaseLetters, UppercaseLetters" />
```

For further information, please see:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you should add an onkeypress function (javascript)

```
function(){ return RejectNonAlphabetCharacters(event);
```

the function should look like this:

```
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode; 
if (charCode>65 and charCode>90)
{charCode is not alphabet}
```